# Calculate river length in each subcatchment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, zonal-statistics

Using ArcGis 10.4

I have suceeded in calculating "maximum upstream river distance to its reach per subcatchment" per subcatchment with the help of this forum (see [Calculate river distance to headwater for every pixel?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271697/calculate-river-distance-to-headwater-for-every-pixel)).

Now I additionally need the **length of the river stretch within each subcatchment**. My idea was to just calculate the **minimum** upstream distance to its reach and then deduct this from the previous maximum distance. But it doesnt work, I run into multiple problems when joining them later. So I was thinking, zonal statistics as table should do the trick. But it doesnt work either.

Any other idea how I could calculate that?

Comment: sound more like splitting your river shp with the catchments, and then calculate the length for each river line

Comment: I agree. Do you have some sort of subcatchment feature?  Then you could do as suggested.

Comment: Hmm. That might be a good idea. Yes I have a featureclass with my subcatchments. 
I tried the split tool but obviously my subcatchments need a character name. I dont have that. How would you proceed?
Thank you!